# ASP.NET template not workin

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I'm building a template in HTML for ASP.NET and I have a line:

```
{% include icons/placeholder.svg width="100%" height="100%" background="#777" color="#777" text=" " title=" " %}
```

but it's showing me the line instead the file..

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Not clear. What sort of template? Are you referring to the common markup that should be loaded on each child page?

Comment: Is it in razor?

Comment: sorry if I wan not clear... This is a bootstrap 4 template with includes this line....

Comment: <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        {% include icons/placeholder.svg width="100%" height="100%" background="#777" color="#777" text=" " title=" " %}
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

Comment: <img src="icons/placeholder.svg" width="100%" height="100%" background="#777" color="#777"/>   give this line

Comment: No way... This shows me the image link broken :(